# I can't make a cleaver. Help?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tinkers-construct

[image]
I have obsidian everything, and it just won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell from the screenshot, but you appear to be using [Tool Rods](https://ftbwiki.org/Tool_Rod), while the recipe calls for **[Tough](https://ftb.gamepedia.com/Tough_Rod)** Rods.